# SharePoint Online - Default Link Type

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharing, external-sharing, defaultlinktype, copylink

I updated the "Default Link Type" to "Direct"(Specific People) both at Tenant level and site level.

At Tenant level, I updated using the URL: https://Tenant-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/ExternalSharing.aspx

At site level, I updated using the PS Script : `Set-SPOsite -Identity SiteURL -DefaultSharingLinkType Direct`

But still when I go to a document library in that site --> select any document --> clicked on "copy Link" ,it shows "People with existing access" as the default value instead of "Specific People"

How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: I think the correct command is : "Set-SPOsite -Identity SiteURL -DefaultSharingLinkType Direct"

Comment: @a1th42: Sorry it was a typo in my question.At site level, it is set to "Direct"(Specific people) correctly

Comment: I don't know how long you've waited, but I have found that many tenant-level settings take several minutes, sometimes up to an hour before the site-level behavior changes.

Comment: @willman Its been 2 days since i set the default link type to "Direct"(Specific People) at site level. The changes are reflecting at site level but at document library/document level, the default value is still showing as "People with existing access"

Comment: 2 days should definitely be more than enough time for it to take effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `DefaultLinkToExistingAccess` is set to TRUE, the DefaultSharingLinkType will be overriden and the default sharing link will be a People with Existing Access.

Execute the following:

```
Set-sposite -Identity SiteURL -DefaultLinkToExistingAccess $false
```

Comment: -DefaultLinkToExistingAccess is not working,may be this functionality is retired

Comment: Actually, it is relatively new, you may have to updated your version of PnP:  `Update-Module SharePointPnPPowerShell*`

Comment: Yes, that is correct. This command is quite new and is still being rolled out by Microsoft. It was supposed to be done by the end of March. But I still dont have this command available in my tenant